# How to handle window or body onscroll in Blazor server side?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I need to capture `onscroll` event of `window` or `body` in my blazor server side application. Right now I implemented this using a script file where I capture the event and do my logics in there.

**For `window`:**

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  //  ... my logics here
}
```

How to capture `onscroll` event of `body` tag? In blazor server side `body` is in `_Host.cshtml` file where I cannot use `@onscroll`.

**For `body`:**

```html
<body onscroll="myFunction()">
```

The above one works but I'm not happy with this implementation while using blazor.

Please assist on how to implement this purely with C#.

Comment: While you can't use Blazor on the body, you can set the body to be non-scrolling and use your component as the scrollable element, then you can use @onscroll on your component - but be aware that is a very chatty event and is bad for performance. What is the end goal here - why do you need to listen to scroll events? There may be another way to do what you need...

Comment: I'm developing a parallax page and I need to activate css class based on sections when the user scrolls. That's the goal

Comment: That should work with a scrollable container in Blazor, but performance will be pretty bad. Did you consider using an intersection observer?

Comment: Sometimes you have to use the right tool for the job and direct access to the Dom is just not available yet in Blazor, so JavaScript ends up being the right tool

Comment: Thanks for the info and tip. I'll look at intersection observer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@[Mister Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658697/mister-magoo) Thanks for pointing me in right direction. I made this to work using `IntersectionObserver`.

Here is what I did,

I removed reference to `window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};` and also removed `onscroll="myFunction()"` from `<body>` tag.

And then called my `IntersectionObserver` function from `OnAfterRenderAsync` in Index.razor component

```cs
@code{

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("highlightMenu");
        }
    }

}
```

`IntersectionObserver` function:

```js
function myFunction() {
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.page-section,.site-header');
    const config = {
        rootMargin: '-55px 0px -85%'
    };

    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function
        (entries, self) {

        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                intersectionHandler(entry);
            }
        });
    }, config);

    sections.forEach(section => observer.observe(section));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Index.html` is the entry point to all Blazor app. Which is a standard HTML document. That will be rendered as `document` which has the scroll events. **You have to use JS Interop** to call JS code to scroll or notify your code of scroll events.

Here is a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Common.JsInterop/) which can handle it for you. See it in action using [demo app](https://blazorextensions.z6.web.core.windows.net/jsinterop#scroll).

**Note: this is using .NET 5 so won't work with Blazor App targeting .NET Core 3.1.**

Answer (score 0):

for me it looks like your _Host.cshtml file is not a razor component file, and therefore you won't be able to implement that logic in a code block (looking at .razor extension).

Comment: So the only way is to go with javascript? The current implementation that I showed above?

Comment: @fingers10 Yes, but you can use JS interopt to code the logic in C#

Comment: @aguafrommars where should I call a js method using JS interop? from which component? since body is not a component from where can I call?

Comment: Add a .js script in your wwwroot folder and inject a `IJSRuntime` instance in the component you want to use it. [The doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.1)